# how can i reroute incoming connection without passing it from my server

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn, ptr-record, stunnel

here is whats happening

i ran a openvpn server on a server outside my coutry and tunneled it using stunnel from a server inside country(because of vpn restrictions i cant connect to it directly)

but it seems like goverment or somebody else dicovered this and since they cant block a ip inside country they are forcing packet loss to and from it(i cant even ping correctly from inside server and the result is very poor connection)

so i cant just make a new server and give the new front server ip to a lot of users

what can i do about it? what i was searching for is to use a reverse dns ,a PTR record so clients connecting to it get a domain and that domain(a ddns) gives back A record of new frontend server.

but idk how to force client to connect to new ip from PTR rather than server ip itself

is there any other solution for it. sorry idk about dns a lot

Comment: Make a tunnel over the Tor network maybe?

Comment: @Ace as i said server have incoming and outgoing packetloss. i cant do tunneling from it

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault. Take a look at the [guidelines](https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask). by how it's written, is hard to understand exactly what you are trying to achieve. If you want a CNAME in DNS or a better way of tunneling traffic like iodine.